# How to remove GIT completely from centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, git, centos-7

I tried `yum remove git` but even after that on running the command `git --version` it is showing `git version 2.16.5` as result.

Later I deleted the directory named **git** and other directories containing `git` data from `root` directory but it proved to be of no help.

I have also tried `remove -rf .git`

Comment: run `which git`. that will tell you where it is currently installed.

Comment: @DavidPostill it is showing `/usr/bin/git` as result - should I just remove it?

Comment: Yes ...........

Answer (score -1):

try this command:

yum erase git-core -y

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it otherwise it may get deleted.